# Is there possible to config map-reduce use hostname rather than IP during data transferring?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp

Currently I am trying to migrate hdfs files between two different hadoop clusters by using `distcp`

The source cluster is isolated in a network, each machine has been associated with both external & internal IPs. Namenode talks to datanode through internal IP address

In the destination side, it's always failed to fetch data when using `distcp`, for it always try to connect to source datanode by using internal IPs of the source side which is invariably inaccessible.

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory: I/O error constructing remote block reader.
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.47.194.252:50010]
```

Is there possible to change IP to hostname in the case ? Then I could mapping the source hostname with external IP in the destination side.

Comment: Look at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsMultihoming.html

Comment: @tk421 thanks! I should have made a close study on official document